# Use Jsch to implement scp and additionally not reinvent the wheel

Tags: java, ant, scp

"How to copy a file using Jsch?" was the question first in place. As using Jsch is complicated and error-prone and also works very low-level, you need to program several lines to get a simple scp working.

So, how do I implement a scp (or even sftp) with as few lines of code as possible in **Java** and not violate the DRY principle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the libraries used by the Ant scp task:

```
package org.example.scp;

import org.apache.tools.ant.Project;
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp;

public class ScpCopyExample {

    public void downloadFile( String remoteFilePath, String localFilePath ) {
        Scp scp = new Scp();
        scp.setFile("username:password@host.example.org:" + remoteFilePath);
        scp.setLocalTofile(localFilePath);
        scp.setProject(new Project()); // prevent a NPE (Ant works with projects)
        scp.setTrust(true); // workaround for not supplying known hosts file

        scp.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScpCopyExample scpDemo = new ScpCopyExample();
        scpDemo.downloadFile("~/test.txt", "testlocal.txt");
    }

}
```

I did this with following jars in my classpath:

- jsch-0.1.48.jar
- ant-jsch-1.6.5.jar
- ant-1.7.0.jar
- ant-launcher-1.7.0.jar

This example can easily be extended to upload files or use SFTP instead.

Comment: Simon, you are my hero for the week.  I have a gradle plugin where I tried using antBuilder and feeding taskdef classpath via reflection.  All my tests worked and deployment failed.  Using your method (which I already used for OS detection but forgot about) works in my test and execution environments.   Thank you, thank you, thank you.   Peter

Comment: @PeterKahn very happy being able to help you!

Answer (score 1):

Few lines as possible? Try this groovy example, which leverages the [ANT scp task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html).

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.apache.ant', module='ant-jsch', version='1.8.4'),
    @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
])

def ant = new AntBuilder()    
ant.scp(file:"helloworld.doc", todir:"mark@remotehost:/home/mark/docs", password:"sEcReT")
```

The [Grape annotations](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape) will download the jar dependencies at run-time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forget to mention that the solution has to be in Java. I will add this to the question. But your way does look very charming.

Comment: @SimonTheSorcerer Understood. Your example also uses the ANT task, so both solutions are basically the same. The linecount difference boils down to the difference in language implementations. (Groovy can be easily compiled into/with Java).

Comment: Both use Ant, this is correct. As I am beginner in Groovy I will not know how to invoke your example from Java, though. And, e.g. how I will need to set up my Maven pom.xml or which libraries I need to download to get it working.

Comment: @SimonTheSorcerer It's pretty easy, using Maven: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Building+Groovy+Projects

Comment: Im missing the point like <code>GroovyScp scp = new GroovyScp(); scp.download(...);</code> which I want to insert in my Java code.